# C++ error C2662 or how to declare in right way

Tags: c++, class, declaration

i get the fallowing error when i compile program:

> vandenynas.cpp(19) error C2662: 'skaiciavimas::showst' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const skaiciavimas' to 'skaiciavimas &'

there is my classes:
first.h

```
    #pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "skaiciavimas.h"
using namespace std;
class vandenynas
{
public:

void duomenys (int i, int a, int a0) const;
string GetName()const;
protected:
        skaiciavimas sk;
};
```

first.cpp

```
    #include "vandenynas.h"
skaiciavimas::v vektorV;
void vandenynas::duomenys (int i, int a, int a0) const
{
        switch (i)
    {
        case 0:
            vektorV.x=a-a0;
            break;
        case 1:
            vektorV.y=a-a0;
            break;
        default:
            vektorV.z=a-a0;
            break;

    }
 sk.showst(vektorV);
}
```

second where is called function.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class skaiciavimas
{
public:
    struct v
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int z;
    };
    void showst(v st);
};
```

.cpp

```
    #include "skaiciavimas.h"

void skaiciavimas::showst(v st)
{
    cout<<st.x<<" "<<st.y<<" "<<st.z<<endl;
}
```

can someone tel where is mistake?

Comment: Please indicate the line where the error happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you declare `vandenynas::duomenys` as a `const` function, i.e. it does not change anything in the object. But it calls `skaiciavimas::showst` which is not declared as `const`, which is not permissible. If you declare one method as `const`, all methods it calls, in itself or an object that is a member of the object, also have to be declared as `const`.

Comment: You can call non-const methods of a different object.

Comment: Sorry, I now see that the object is a member. I changed my vote.

Answer (score 2):

`skaiciavimas::showst` is not a const member function. Since `vandenynas::duomenys` is a const member function, all members of `this` are considered const and therefore `skaiciavimas::showst` cannot be called.

Comment: You can call non-const methods of a different object.

Comment: Sorry, I now see that the object is a member. I changed my vote.